# How to create an incremental pipeline in fabric

Tags: pipeline, microsoft-fabric, incremental

I want to create a pipeline to avoid keep loading the data that is already in the warehouse.
I first created scripts to clear my dimension and fact tables (fact_Transactions).
I then, inserted the dataflows to load the dimension and fact tables, and then tried to add a script to remove the old data. However, my script is always failing.

This is the script a colleague told me to try:

```
DELETE
FROM fact_Transactions
Where fk_date IN
(
SELECT
CAST(LEFT(fact_Transactions.fk.date,4) + '-'
    RIGHT(LEFT(fact_Transactions.fk.date,6),2) + '-'
    RIGHT(fact_Transactions.fk.date,2 ) AS DATE) as 
          dw_proper_date
FROM fact_Transactions
);
```

However, neither I understand it very well, neither it runs successfully.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [ask] and then use the appropriate tags for your question. [tag:fabric] is a Python library, but this code doesn't look like Python. Could you please READ the tag wikis (click on them, read the top bit at least) to make sure you've used the correct tags on your question? Do [edit] accordingly.

Comment: Can you not use a merge statement? It will only add in items that do not meet those conditions? whats the error with the DELETE??